# Create blob from blob slices

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

Is there a function that can reassemble a Blob from slices of the Blob in Firefox / Chrome. i.e. perform the reverse of the slice() operation?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [***Blob***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) constructor itself can do just that

```
var b1 = new Blob(['abcdef']), // Inital Blob
    b2,                        // re-created Blob to go here
    s1 = b1.slice(0, 3),       // a slice
    s2 = b1.slice(3, 6);       // another slice

// now reverse the slicing
b2 = new Blob([s1, s2]);
b2.size; // 6
```

If you really want to double-check

```
var f = new FileReader();
f.onload = function () {console.log(this.result);};
f.readAsText(b1); // "abcdef"
f.readAsText(b2); // "abcdef"
// and the slices
f.readAsText(s1); // "abc"
f.readAsText(s2); // "def"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried with BlobBuilder append() but found it was deprecated. And I did try this too but found it not working (think it was a problem with my sliced blobs as this seems to work fine now).